# Fisher exact test manual input of observed and expected

Tags: r, inference, proportion, fishers-exact-test

I have a 4x4 table and I want to test if observed proportion equal to a given expected proportion I provide.  Because the counts between observed and expected are very different, I am interested in percent / proportion comparisons.  I searched for a few days but never found a similar example, I only found textbook examples where the expected values are calculated not provided.  Is this possible with Fisher exact test?  I would try chi square but this is mxn not 2x2.   Working code is below

```
#Observed proportions
datObs <- data.frame(
  "y1" = c(0.5, 0.125, 0.25, 0.125),
  "y2" = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0),
  "y3" = c(0, 0.86, 0, 0.14),
  "y4" = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0),

  row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I want to know if they equal these given proportions

```
datExp <- data.frame(
"y1" = c(0.25, 0.56, 0.18, 0.01),
"y2" = c(0.18, 0.63, 0.18, 0.01),
"y3" = c(0.14, 0.63, 0.20, 0.03),
"y4" = c(0.12, 0.67, 0.17, 0.04),

row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

datObs
datExp
```

for exact counts, these are the data

```
# observed data

datObs2 <- data.frame(
"y1" = c(8, 2, 4, 2),
"y2" = c(2, 2, 0, 0),
"y3" = c(0, 6, 1, 0),
"y4" = c(3, 4, 0, 3),

row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


datExp2 <- data.frame(
"y1" = c(316, 706, 37, 11),
"y2" = c(284, 983, 24, 18),
"y3" = c(193, 874, 51, 47),
"y4" = c(209, 1139, 56, 68),

row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dataObs2
dataExp2

chisq.test(datObs, datExp)
fisher.test(datObs, datExp)
```

Thanx

Comment: If you have counts, then stick with the counts.  You will lose information converting to percentages/proportions. The is a huge difference between (1 out of 2) and (500 out of 1000).

Comment: Yes I have counts.  But how do I compare the proportions with a Fisher test given I am providing the specific expected values?  I need to test that given certain proportions in counts that my observed values match the same proportions.